# textures in an imported mesh?

Tags: mesh, collada, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There is a simple way to add the textures to a mesh? I have imported few models form 3dwarehouse, when I export them to .dae, I get the mesh that I can correctly use in Gazebo , but of course without the textures. It is any easy way to "attach" the textures to my models? I use Gazebo 7.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19029/textures-in-an-imported-mesh?/) by [Mansan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4773/mansan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 68 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Perhaps these related answers can help you:

- http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1500/can-textures-be-added-to-simple-objects-from-my-own-source/
- http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7922/ground-plane-texture-image/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/49643/gazebo-usage-of-textures-pictures/

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) with karma: 609 on 2018-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2018-04-17**:
Those are good answers. There's some information in [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=color_model#AboutTextures) about textures too.

**Comment by [Mansan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4773/mansan/) on 2018-05-01**:
Thanks for the answer!These links show how attach a texture to a 3d mesh, but I have another problem (And I think this can be solve easily, or at all). If I have a model (.dae) and two textures (for example in a tree, I have e texture for the leaves and another for the branches/trunk). It is not possible to set it rigth in Gazebo , if the tree 3D mesh is imported as one file, rigth?

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) on 2018-05-01**:
@Mansan you may be able to accomplish some of that using Ogre scripts (there's a small example of a texture being applied 4 times to different sides of a cube in the link @sloretz shared). That's the only thing I could think of (no idea if possible).